# Manually building a tile server

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, ubuntu, mapnik, rendering

I use this instruction http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/

I have the problem on the step "Starting your tileserver"

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/renderd
sudo chown username /var/run/renderd
renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
```

The problem:

```
renderd[4620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'shape' (searched in: /usr/lib/mapnik/input) (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[4620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'shape' (searched in: /usr/lib/mapnik/input) (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[4620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'shape' (searched in: /usr/lib/mapnik/input) (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[4620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'shape' (searched in: /usr/lib/mapnik/input) (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 8, number 1
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(8) xml(default), z(0), x(0), y(0)
renderd[4620]: Received request for map layer 'default' which failed to load
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 0 left
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 8, number 1
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(8) xml(default), z(0), x(0), y(0)
renderd[4620]: Received request for map layer 'default' which failed to load
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 0 left
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 8, number 1
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(8) xml(default), z(0), x(0), y(0)
renderd[4620]: Received request for map layer 'default' which failed to load
renderd[4620]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 0 left
```

Update 1: One of the problem was the file "renderd.conf". here is file without error.

```
[renderd]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=2
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats


[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
font_dir_recurse=1

[default]
URI=/osm_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/home/map/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml
HOST=localhost
TILESIZE=256
CORS=*
```

But I have another errors:

```
renderd[8967]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Shape Plugin: shapefile '/usr/local/share/world)boundaries/shoreline_300.shp' does not exist (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[8967]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Shape Plugin: shapefile '/usr/local/share/world)boundaries/shoreline_300.shp' does not exist (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
```

Update: The question is solved

Comment: See the solution here: http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/1347-how-do-i-use-the-xml-file-created-by-export-to-mapnik-xml

Comment: My version of mapnik is 2.0.3-pre. So, I have another problem

Comment: When i do
renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf my server send me this error renderd[78029]: An error ocurred while loading the map layer 'default': Shape Plugin: shapefile '/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/shp/ne_10m_populated_places/ne_10m_populated_places.shp' does not exist encountered during parsing of layer 'ne_places' in Layer at line 45546 of
'/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml' Can give me some hint to resolve this problem? Regards

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93403)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was almost certainly that you had a stray bracket:

```
renderd[8967]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Shape Plugin: shapefile '/usr/local/share/world)boundaries/shoreline_300.shp' does not exist (encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in map '/home/oleg/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
```

Note: world **)** boundaries

Can you close this question off?